# How to update/refresh Combobox Items/content at Runtime when Combobox Itemsource is binded to a List/ObservableCollection in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, data-binding, combobox

I have a WPF application where I use a ComboBox. My ComboBox ItemSource is bind to a List <> which I populate from C# in background.

Here is the C# code of that `List<>` :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,  INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
 public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

// Main code
                  List<AudioDevice> devices = new List<AudioDevice>();
              HRESULT hr = HRESULT.E_FAIL;
              Guid CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = new Guid("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}");
              Type MMDeviceEnumeratorType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, true);
              object MMDeviceEnumerator = Activator.CreateInstance(MMDeviceEnumeratorType);
              IMMDeviceEnumerator pMMDeviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)MMDeviceEnumerator;
              if (pMMDeviceEnumerator != null)
              {
                  string sIdDefaultRender = null;
                  string sIdDefaultCapture = null;
                  IMMDevice pDefaultDevice = null;
                  hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eConsole, out pDefaultDevice);
                  if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                  {
                      IntPtr hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                      hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                      sIdDefaultRender = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice);
                  }
                  hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eCapture, ERole.eConsole, out pDefaultDevice);
                  if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                  {
                      IntPtr hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                      hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                      sIdDefaultCapture = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice);
                  }
                  IMMDeviceCollection pDeviceCollection = null;
                  hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eAll, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE | DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED, out pDeviceCollection);
                  if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                  {
                      uint nDevices = 0;
                      hr = pDeviceCollection.GetCount(out nDevices);
                      devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = "System default", Direction = "Playback", Id = sIdDefaultRender, Default = true });
                      for (uint i = 0; i < nDevices; i++)
                      {
                          IMMDevice pDevice = null;
                          hr = pDeviceCollection.Item(i, out pDevice);
                          if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                          {
                              IPropertyStore pPropertyStore = null;
                              hr = pDevice.OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, out pPropertyStore);
                              if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                              {
                                  string sFriendlyName = null;
                                  string sDesc = null;
                                  PROPVARIANT pv = new PROPVARIANT();
                                  hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(ref PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, out pv);
                                  if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                                  {
                                      sFriendlyName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pv.pwszVal);
                                  }
                                  hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(ref PKEY_Device_DeviceDesc, out pv);
                                  if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                                  {
                                      sDesc = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pv.pwszVal);
                                  }
                                  IntPtr hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                                  hr = pDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                                  string sId = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                                  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                                  IMMEndpoint pEndpoint = null;
                                  pEndpoint = (IMMEndpoint)pDevice;
                                  EDataFlow eDirection = EDataFlow.eAll;
                                  hr = pEndpoint.GetDataFlow(out eDirection);
                                  //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("\tDirection : " + eDirection.ToString());
                                  string sDirection = "";
                                  if (eDirection == EDataFlow.eRender)
                                      sDirection = "Playback";
                                  else if (eDirection == EDataFlow.eCapture)
                                      sDirection = "Recording";
                                  int nState = 0;
                                  hr = pDevice.GetState(out nState);
                                  if ((nState == DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE))
                                  {
                                      devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = sFriendlyName, Direction = sDirection, Id = sId, Default = (sId == sIdDefaultRender || (sId == sIdDefaultCapture)) });
                                      //sFriendlyName += (sId == sIdDefaultRender || sId == sIdDefaultCapture) ? " (System default)" : "";
                                      //devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = sFriendlyName, Direction = sDirection, Default = (sId == sIdDefaultRender || (sId == sIdDefaultCapture)) });
                                      ////devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = sFriendlyName, Direction = sDirection, Default = (sId == sIdDefaultRender || (sId == sIdDefaultCapture)) });
                                  }
                                  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPropertyStore);
                              }
                              Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDevice);
                          }
                      }
                      devices.Insert(devices.Count - 0, new AudioDevice() { Name = "Selected application ...", Direction = "Recording", Id = "Idlast", Default = false });
                  }
                  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDeviceCollection);
                  ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(devices);
                  lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Direction"));
                  
                  ObservableCollection<AudioDevice> lcv2 = new(devices);                   

                  this.cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv; // ComboBox Itemsource by using ListCollectionView

                  cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv2; // ComboBox Itemsource by using ObservableCollection
              

    }
          }
          public class AudioDevice
                  {
                      public string Name { get; set; }
                      public string Direction { get; set; }
                      public string Id { get; set; }
                      public bool Default { get; set; }
    
      public override string ToString()
                 {
                     return Name;
                 }
    
              }
```

Actually, I can retrieve the default available Audio Devices using this code, though this code is a Gem, you can use this code in your personal project.

If you carefully see the code then You see this line `this.cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv;` That means the `List<>` is added as ItemSource of the ComboBox. My problem is, if I run this code then I easily retrieve the default audio devices but suppose, I add a new device and the application is running then my WPF application is unable to detect that, it can only detect the new device if I restart the application.

At first I think it's the fault of  `ListCollectionView` (`List<>`) so, instead of `ListCollectionView` I use `ObservableCollection`. Because according to the concept of WPF, a `List<>` can not refresh/update UI but an `ObservableCollection` can. But still the result is same. New devices are only detected if I restart my application, not in runtime.

I also try to solve this problem using ViewModel prospective, but the problem is same. I also give some code snippet of ViewModel, so that it can be easier to understand that how I applied the Binding on Combobox Itemsource.

Here is the ViewModel Code :

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<AudioDevice> devices;
  public ObservableCollection<AudioDevice> Devices
    {
        get { return devices; }
        set
        {
            devices = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Devices");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And here is, How I bind this in my ComboBox itemsource :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="10" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" Height="24.2" Width="246.5" Margin="121,7,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedValuePath="Content"></ComboBox>
```

But still it has no result, my WPF application is unable to detect the new available devices until I restart my application. The problem is same, it does not matter if I add combobox itemsource from code behind or binding the Combobox Itemsource from a ViewModel.

Though most people suggest me to use `CollectionChanged` event on ObservableCollection. I also use that but still the problem is same.

Here is the code of CollectionChanged:

```
devices = new ObservableCollection<AudioDevice>();
this.devices.CollectionChanged += Devices_CollectionChanged;

 ......................

private void Devices_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {              
            devices.Reverse(); // Just to test if the CollectionChanged method is working or not.
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            devices.Reverse();
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
        {
            devices.Reverse();
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            devices.Reverse();
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            devices.Reverse();
        }

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I almost stuck here for two months. Though I found some hack/tricky method, what I have done is, I written a separate method and I put the retrieve audio devices code there and each time I called the method in ComboBox DropDownOpened, Now it can successfully detect any changes to the Combobox items but there are two main problem, in this way the previously selected Combobox item is ruined because each time whenever the Combobox dropdown is open the Combobox list is refresh there no selected item.

This How I written the method :

```
 public void Cmb1Update()
        {

            // My AudioDeviceList Code

            List<AudioDevice> devices = new();

            //ObservableCollection<AudioDevice> devices = new();


            HRESULT hr = HRESULT.E_FAIL;
            Guid CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = new Guid("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}");
            Type MMDeviceEnumeratorType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, true);
            object MMDeviceEnumerator = Activator.CreateInstance(MMDeviceEnumeratorType);
            IMMDeviceEnumerator pMMDeviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)MMDeviceEnumerator;
            if (pMMDeviceEnumerator != null)
.............................

}
```

And I called this `Cmb1Update()` method in the Combobox dropdown open event :

```
 private void cmb1_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cmb1Update();
        }
```

..
}
}

Comment: Just using some logic, it doesn't make sense to suspect the source collection if you are not able to retrieve the new items in the first place. When/where exactly do you start a new search for new devices? You must observe system events or the events of the API you are using get notified when devices are connected or disconnected. Such kind of event must be your trigger to search for new or old devices.

Comment: Using the drop down opening event as a trigger doesn't make much sense. If a user opens the ComboBox multiple consecutive times you  currently search for new devices every time. You didn't even track new/old items. You just throw everything away even when there are no changes. This behavior will also make your control to act slow or even unresponsive. Why do you repeat `pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()` multiple times? You should move it into a for-loop.

Comment: I understand what you want to say, that means there no issue in List<> and ObservableCollection, it's the fault of those win32/C++ code. Someone from Microsoft gave me this and it working fine but there only one issue. Can you please give me an authentic solution. Because I rarely know about these Old win32/C++. If you give me solution I definitely accept your answer.

Comment: It's not the fault of the code Microsft gave to you. It's the way you use it. I asked you where and when exactly you were calling this code. It looks like you run it from a constructor.

Comment: If you are not too familiar with using the Win32 API or don't want write all the code by yourself you should use a 3rd party library like NAudio.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I use this in the MainWindow.XAML.CS. If you carefully see those win32/C++ code then you can see in the last, ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(devices); and this.cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv;  this is how I add this as Combobox item source. Now tell me how I solve this?

Comment: Do you read my comments? Or do you have trouble to understand what I'm asking? You never really answer my questions. It's like you ignore them or haven't read them. Last try: I need to know from where your code that queries the devices is executed. I don't need the name of the file. I need the method and the method that is calling this method. Just provide some context so that I can see what your application is doing. To make things clear: don't run this code from the constructor. The constructor is only executed on construction and if the declaring class is your main window it's executed once

Comment: Please edit the first code section of your question and show the complete method including the signature and the code that calls this method.

Comment: I just put the code in mainwindow MainWindow.XAML.CS. I already updated the first code section. I just populate the combobox from this line this.cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv. Forget about the ViewModel and other things.

Comment: The question, as asked, seems to be unrelated to C++. Please use the appropriate language tag, presumably C#.

Comment: Now, give me a solution, I accept your answer, I already updated the code.

Comment: I already gave you a solution. Just read my comments. I wrote twice that you must not execute the code from the constructor as it will only run once! You must find an event that you can observe. The event must notify about new/removed devices. Then execute the code from this handler. I wrote all this before.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to fetch audio devices is only executed once, because it is implemented in the constructor. In your case the constructor is only called once on application startup (construction of `MainWindow`).
Instead, you must observe device events and execute your code every time a new device was added or an existing device was removed.

I recommend to use the [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration?view=winrt-22621) namespace. It's part of the Windows Runtime API ([Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)). It's more convenient to use than the Win32 API.
The following example shows how to initialize a class with all current audio output and input devices and how to observe the system for audio device changes:

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation> AudioDevices { get; }
  private DeviceWatcher AudioOutputDeviceWatcher { get; set; }
  private DeviceWatcher AudioInputDeviceWatcher { get; set; }
  
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AudioDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    /* Observe audio capture (input) and audio render (output) devices */
    this.AudioOutputDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.AudioRender);
    this.AudioOutputDeviceWatcher.Added += OnAudioDeviceAdded;
    this.AudioOutputDeviceWatcher.Removed += OnAudioDeviceRemoved;
    this.AudioOutputDeviceWatcher.Updated += OnAudioDeviceUpdated;

    this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.AudioCapture);
    this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher.Added += OnAudioDeviceAdded;
    this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher.Removed += OnAudioDeviceRemoved;
    this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher.Updated += OnAudioDeviceUpdated;

    this.AudioOutputDeviceWatcher.Start();
    this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher.Start();

    // Call 'this.AudioInputDeviceWatcher.Stop()` to end device observation
  }

  private void OnAudioOutputDeviceRemoved(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInformationUpdate)
  {
    DeviceInformation deviceInfoToRemove = this.AudioDevices.First(deviceInfo => deviceInfo.Id == deviceInformationUpdate.Id);
    _ = this.AudioDevices.Remove(deviceInfoToRemove);
  }

  private void OnAudioOutputDeviceAdded(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInformation) 
    => this.AudioDevices.Add(deviceInformation);

  private void OnAudioOutputDeviceUpdated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInformationUpdate)
  {
    DeviceInformation deviceInfoToUpdate = this.AudioDevices.First(deviceInfo => deviceInfo.Id == deviceInformationUpdate.Id);
    deviceInfoToUpdate.Update(deviceInformationUpdate);
  }
}
```